# Passing checked checkboxes values to another JSP using Javascript

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, checkbox

This is ,my code in JSP. I need to pass checked checkbox values from a.jsp to b.jsp through Javascript. I have no idea how to do it. Please help me.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
        <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="b.jsp">
            My Favourite Colors are
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="blue">Blue
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="green">Green
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="Yellow">Yellow
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="Red">Red
            <input type="checkbox" name="cb1" value="white">White
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `JavaScript` or `jQuery`. When we click on `submit` button then the `checked` values will be sent to the `b.jsp` and in `b.jsp` we can access the values from the `request` object. To access the values use the following code in `b.jsp`:

```
<%
   String[] values = request.getParameterValues("cb1");

   if (values!=null)
     for (String val: values) {
        System.out.println("Value "+ val);
    }
%>
```

**Note**: If no checkbox checked then `request.getParameterValues()` method returns `null` value.

Answer (score 0):

You can not directly post data to 'b.jsp'. You will need to create a servlet in middle.

```
<form method="post" action="ServletNameHere">
```

When the form is submitted, The control will go to the servlet.

```
<input type="submit">
```

In the servlet you can get the data you have sent from 'a.jsp' put it in a model and redirect to b.jsp.

Fetch the values from the model.